# Android SeekBar old progress not removed

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have an issue with my Android SeekBar, I press at one each location along the bar and the bar moves to this location but it does not remove the old locations so I get a strange ghosting effect as seen in the image.

[image: Screen Capture from my device]

has anyone seen this before? or knows what it could be?

my layout file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opt_back_button"
        android:text="@string/opt_back_button_text"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/opt_test_seek_bar"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my main Java file is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OptionsMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the content view to the options menu
    setContentView(R.layout.options_menu);

    // get string from intent that started this activity
    Intent source_intent = getIntent();
    String message = source_intent.getStringExtra("games.longrun.toroidtussle.MESSAGE");

    // display the message as a toast
    Toast test_toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    test_toast.show();

    // initialise the listeners for this activity
    initialise_listeners();
}

    private void initialise_listeners()
    {
        // get reference to the seekbar
        SeekBar test_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.opt_test_seek_bar);

        // set listener for seek bar events
        test_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                int progress = seekBar.getProgress();

                Toast.makeText(OptionsMenuActivity.this, "Progress = " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found out what the issue was for this.

I had set a style which included the line

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

which I changed to

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black_overlay</item>
```